# In the game of sequence: A sequence of more than 5 coins

Tags: sequence

In the game of sequence, if you create a sequence of more than 5 in one move, do you have to declare which 5 coins make the sequence?

Comment: I don't think the rules say that you have to declare when you make a sequence. But I don't think it matters, as a row of more than 5 can only count as one sequence, since sequences can only share one coin. (A row of 9 or 10 would count as two sequences by this rule)

Comment: It matters because of the rule against *breaking* an opponent's sequence. So if I have 6 coins in a row, you clearly can't mess with the middle 4, but what about the two on the ends - can you mess with both, neither, or something else (like the one that was played second)?

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Good point, I forgot that rule.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to declare which row of five is the sequence, as any row of five is protected by the rule:

> You cannot remove a marker chip that
> is already part of a completed SEQUENCE. Once a SEQUENCE is achieved by a player or a team, it cannot
> be broken.

Where a Sequence is defined as:

> A Sequence is a connected series of five of the same color marker chip in a straight line, either up and
> down, across or diagonally on the playing surface.

Together, these rules prevent any connected series of five chips from being broken.

As mentioned in my comment, any series less than 9 is only valid as one sequence for scoring. A series of 9 can count as two sequences overlapping by one coin.

[Rule Source](https://www.nordicgames.is/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Sequence_Rules_EN.pdf)